# Tomcat-Maven 401 error

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I tried to deploy my application using **mvn tomcat7:deploy**  command.
 The weird part is that my build was successful but above that line I am getting 
     **

```
 - tomcatManager status code:401, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized

**


I have provided the neccessary reference files
XML inside tomcat-users.xml

 <tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-script,admin"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin,tomcat"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Below is the code for my Maven settings file

```
  <server>
   <id>TomcatServer</id>
   <username>admin</username>
   <password>tomcat</password>
  </server>
```

POM.xml file Contents

```
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.1</version>
     <configuration>
       <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
       <!--  <server>TomcatServer</server> -->
       <server>TomcatServer</server>
       <username>admin</username>
       <password>tomcat</password>
       <path>/Spring-security</path>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Please provide solution on how to resolve this 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your deploy URL to `http://localhost:8080/manager/text`. See "[Deploy A New Application Remotely](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely)".

Also, I'm assuming you are using the `mvn` goal `tomcat7:deploy`.

Comment: I already tried the URL that you have mentioned.Still the same issue. Ya i am using mvn tomcat7:deply command

Comment: Hmm .. HTTP status 401 indicates auth fail or auth not present (vs. 403 "you'll never be able to do that"). The only thing I've got at the moment is trying `tomcat7-maven-plugin` version `2.2`.

Comment: One more thing: you didn't mention what version of Tomcat you are using.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The version of tomcat that I am using is Tomcat 7.0.54.